# ¿Cómo añadir líneas a un fichero y editarlas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Buenas

Veran soy nuevo en python y necesito ayuda para leer archivos txt.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
id = str(input("DIGITE ID ESTUDIANTE"))
nombre = str(input("digite nombre"))
edad = str(input("digite edad"))
ciudad = str(input("digite direccion"))

def grabartxt():
    archi=open('datos.txt','a')

    archi.write("ID:")
    archi.write(id)
    archi.write("\n")
    archi.write('Nombre:')
    archi.write(nombre)
    archi.write("\n")
    archi.write("Edad:")
    archi.write(edad)
    archi.write("\n")
    archi.write("direccion:")
    archi.write(ciudad)
    archi.write("\n")
    archi.close()
```

Lo que necesito es que, ya creado el archivo txt con la informacion de varias
personas, poder buscar una informacion en especifico, digamos que el id, y 
ademas poder modificarlo si lo requiero.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no lo veo muy complicado. En primer lugar crearía un archivo CSV para mayor facilidad de uso. Segundo, crearía una clase `Student` en donde almacene los valores de cada estudiante, esta clase tendría dos métodos: uno para llenar datos y otro para ponerlo en modo de edición. Aparte, tendría una clase que actúe como [*Repositorio*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) sobre el archivo de estudiantes para que *añada*, *busque* y *edite* estudiantes. Por último, pondría un menú dedicado a la opción *buscar* con las opciones: *editar* y *volver* (al menú principal).

```
import sys
import time
import fileinput
from os import system
from os.path import isfile

class Student:
  def fill(self):
    self.id = input("ID: ")
    self.name = input("Nombre: ")
    self.age = int(input("Edad: "))
    self.address = input("Dirección: ")

  def edit_mode(self):
    self.id = input("ID: (enter to skip) ") or self.id
    self.name = input("Nombre: (enter to skip) ") or self.name
    self.age = input("Edad: (enter to skip) ") or self.age
    self.address = input("Dirección: (enter to skip) ") or self.address

  def to_csv_line(self):
    return f"{self.id},{self.name},{self.age},{self.address}"

class StudentRepository:
  @classmethod
  def create(self, student):
    with open("students.csv", "a") as file:
      file.write("\n")
      file.write(student.to_csv_line())

  @classmethod
  def edit(self, student):
    with fileinput.FileInput("students.csv", inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
      for line in file:
        data = line.split(",")
        if (data[0] == student.id):
          print(student.to_csv_line())
          return None

  @classmethod
  def search(__self, id):
    student = None
    with open("students.csv", "r") as file:
      for line in file:
        data = line.split(",")
        if data[0] == id:
          student = Student()
          student.id = data[0]
          student.name = data[1]
          student.age = int(data[2])
          student.address = data[3]
          return student


# Menú principal
def menu():
  option = input("""
  +==========================================+
  |                                          |
  |          Control de estudiantes          |
  |                                          |
  +==========================================+

  [?] Seleccione opción:

  1. Ingresar un estudiante
  2. Buscar un estudiante
  3. Salir

  > """)

  if option == "1":
    student = Student()
    student.fill()
    StudentRepository.create(student)
    print("""
  [✓] Estudiante creado.
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
    """)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    system("clear")
    return menu()

  if option == "2":
    id = input("\nIngresa el ID: ")
    student = StudentRepository.search(id)
    if student is not None:
      return search_menu(student)
    else:
      print("""
  [✕] Estudiante no encontrado.
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
      """)
      time.sleep(1.5)
      system("clear") # limpia la pantalla
      menu()
  if option == "3":
    print("Good Bye")
    sys.exit(0)

# Menú de búsqueda
def search_menu(student):
  option = input(f"""
  [✓] Estudiante encontrado:

  ID: {student.id}
  Nombre: {student.name}
  Edad: {student.age}
  Dirección: {student.address}

  [?] Seleccione opción:

  1. Editar estudiante
  3. Volver

  > """)

  if (option == "1"):
    student.edit_mode()
    StudentRepository.edit(student)
    print("""
  [✓] Estudiante actualizado:
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
    """)
    time.sleep(2)
    system("clear")
    return menu()
  if option == "3":
    system("clear")
    return menu()

menu()
```

---

**Nota:** el código debe correrse en Python 3.6 o reemplazar la interpolación de texto. También supongo puede mejorarse con el uso de lambdas, pero no estoy muy familiarizado aún con ese concepto en Python.

Comment: tu idea es muy buena te lo agradesco , solo una consulta como hago si  ingreso un nuevo estudiante y si este ya esta  que me diga que ya se encuentra inscrito

Comment: me puedes ayudar a la hora de reescribir el archivo students no lo hace creo q la falla esta en esta linea  with fileinput.FileInput("students.csv", inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file: pero no estoy seguro

Comment: @LuisDavidJimenez El código está probado en Python 3.6. ¿Obtienes algún error?

Comment: @LuisDavidJimenez Lo olvidaba. Si estás en Windows elimina las instrucciones `system("clear")` porque solo funciona en UNIX.

Comment: si modifico algun estudiante me crea dos archivos students.csv(queda en blanco) y students.csv.bak y si realizo una busqueda de alguno ya ingresado me dice que no esta,esto ultimo solo pasa si antes intente modificarlo

Comment: El parámetro `backup` es opcional. Puedes quitarlo cuanto quieras. Sobre la búsqueda, fíjate que en el código realizo una búsqueda por ID, y éste **es el primer campo**.

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar por alguna razon no reescribe los datos sino que los deja en blanco, yo uso el python 3.6 como interprete y trabajo en pycharm sera por eso ?

Answer (score 0):

Pues seguro que hay maneras más eficientes de hacer esto pero podrías leer todo el archivo volcandolo en un array. Buscar el ID y si lo encuentras sustituir valores.Siguiendo un poco el formato que envías:

```
    def buscartxt():
        try:
            archi=open('datos.txt','r+');
        except FileNotFoundError:
            ## Si archivo Nuevo directamente grabo
            grabartxt();
        else:
            # Leo el archivo completamente
            with open('datos.txt', 'r') as file:
                datos = file.readlines()
            # Busco si está el ID en el archivo
            encontrado = False;
            buscoId = "ID:"+id+'\n'
            for i,v in enumerate(datos):
                if v == buscoId:
                    # Id encontrado. Reemplazo todo
                    datos[i+1] = 'Nombre:'+nombre+'\n';
                    datos[i+2] = 'Edad:'+edad+'\n';
                    datos[i+3] = 'direccion:'+ciudad+'\n';
                    encontrado = True;
                    break;
            # Si he encontrado el ID, grabo todo el archivo, si no, proceso de grabar txt
            if encontrado is True:
                archi = open('datos.txt', 'w')
                for linea in datos:
                    archi.write(linea)
            else : 
                grabartxt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es leer el fichero línea por linea. ¿Es necesario que los datos los guardes en distintas líneas? Porque te sería más fácil en una única:

id:1;nombre:a;edad:b;direccion:c

Mientras recorres línea por línea es separar cada una de las cadenas separadas por ";" utilizando la función split(), después por ":" y comparar si el id corresponde con el especificado.

Comment: podria ser en una misma cadena pero como haria para cambiar un dato o buscarlo?