# Ayuda en archivos Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo este código:

```
import sys
import time
import fileinput
from os import system
from os.path import isfile

class Student:
  def fill(self):
    self.id = input("ID: ")
    self.name = input("Nombre: ")
    self.age = int(input("Edad: "))
    self.address = input("Dirección: ")

  def edit_mode(self):
    self.id = input("ID: (enter to skip) ") or self.id
    self.name = input("Nombre: (enter to skip) ") or self.name
    self.age = input("Edad: (enter to skip) ") or self.age
    self.address = input("Dirección: (enter to skip) ") or self.address

  def to_csv_line(self):
    return f"{self.id},{self.name},{self.age},{self.address}"

class StudentRepository:
  @classmethod
  def create(self, student):
    with open("students.csv", "a") as file:
      file.write("\n")
      file.write(student.to_csv_line())

  @classmethod
  def edit(self, student):
    with fileinput.FileInput("students.csv", inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
      for line in file:
        data = line.split(",")
        if (data[0] == student.id):
          print(student.to_csv_line())
          return None

  @classmethod
  def search(__self, id):
    student = None
    with open("students.csv", "r") as file:
      for line in file:
        data = line.split(",")
        if data[0] == id:
          student = Student()
          student.id = data[0]
          student.name = data[1]
          student.age = int(data[2])
          student.address = data[3]
          return student


# Menú principal
def menu():
  option = input("""
  +==========================================+
  |                                          |
  |          Control de estudiantes          |
  |                                          |
  +==========================================+

  [?] Seleccione opción:

  1. Ingresar un estudiante
  2. Buscar un estudiante
  3. Salir

  > """)

  if option == "1":
    student = Student()
    student.fill()
    StudentRepository.create(student)
    print("""
  [✓] Estudiante creado.
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
    """)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    system("clear")
    return menu()

  if option == "2":
    id = input("\nIngresa el ID: ")
    student = StudentRepository.search(id)
    if student is not None:
      return search_menu(student)
    else:
      print("""
  [✕] Estudiante no encontrado.
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
      """)
      time.sleep(1.5)
      system("clear") # limpia la pantalla
      menu()
  if option == "3":
    print("Good Bye")
    sys.exit(0)

# Menú de búsqueda
def search_menu(student):
  option = input(f"""
  [✓] Estudiante encontrado:

  ID: {student.id}
  Nombre: {student.name}
  Edad: {student.age}
  Dirección: {student.address}

  [?] Seleccione opción:

  1. Editar estudiante
  3. Volver

  > """)

  if (option == "1"):
    student.edit_mode()
    StudentRepository.edit(student)
    print("""
  [✓] Estudiante actualizado:
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
    """)
    time.sleep(2)
    system("clear")
    return menu()
  if option == "3":
    system("clear")
    return menu()

menu()
```

y suspuestamente debería funcionar bien pero no me guarda la información que cambio sino que el archivo se queda en blanco.

Comment: Luis me acabo de dar cuenta que el código que muestras en realidad pertenece a la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63191/15089) de @GustavoGarcía. Deberías al menos comentar este aspecto o enlazar a tu antigua pregunta. Por otro lado, si una respuesta te fue útil como parece que lo fue la de Gustavo (tiene su trabajo realizar todo ese código) deberías [aceptarla](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas) para reconocer su trabajo y mostrar la utilidad de la respuesta a otros usuarios según el funcionamiento de este sítio.

Comment: si disculpa por eso le doy todo su credito a Gustavo,lo que paso es tengo un error que no puedo corregir y gustavo no me ha podido responder y es urgente

Comment: Mira mi respuesta en esta pregunta. He probado el código y funciona sin problemas aparentemente. Y recuerda lo de aceptar las respuestas, esta es la forma de dar crédito en SO. Si es para una tarea académica yo me preocuparía por entender el código, el código de Gustavo es relativamente complejo si no dominas la POO. También usa características que solo existen en Python 3.6 como son los literales de cadena formateados (si este código se ejecuta en versiones anteriores a la 3.6 no va a funcionar). Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El método de clase `edit` de la clase `StudentRepository` tal y como está solo escribe en el archivo el estudiante editado. Para que solo modifique la línea de ese estudiante y copie las otras hay que recorrer todo el archivo y por cada fila llamar a `print`. En el código solo se llama `print` si el `id` coincide con el estudiante editado por lo que se escribe esa linea y después se rompe el ciclo mediante el `return`.

Por otro lado hay incosistencias con los saltos de linea. La función `print` añade un nuevo salto de línea por defecto, salto de línea que ya está incluido por el método `create` y que no es eliminado por el método `search` cuando crea cada instancia. Todo ello ocasiona que al editar estudiantes se creen líneas vacías en el documento.

Se pueden seguir diferentes estrategias, por ejemplo una de ellas sería:

1. Hacer que el formatted string literal de `create` ya incluyera el salto de línea.
2. En `search` hacer un `strip` sobre cada línea para eliminar los saltos de linea.
3. Eliminar el salto de linea automático del `print` o usar `sys.stdout` en su lugar.

Con esto creo que no se te deben crear lineas en blanco en ningún momento.

El código quedaría así:

```
import sys
import time
import fileinput
from os import system
from os.path import isfile

class Student:
  def fill(self):
    self.id = input("ID: ")
    self.name = input("Nombre: ")
    self.age = int(input("Edad: "))
    self.address = input("Dirección: ")

  def edit_mode(self):
    self.id = input("ID: (enter to skip) ") or self.id
    self.name = input("Nombre: (enter to skip) ") or self.name
    self.age = input("Edad: (enter to skip) ") or self.age
    self.address = input("Dirección: (enter to skip) ") or self.address

  def to_csv_line(self):
    return f"{self.id},{self.name},{self.age},{self.address}\n"

class StudentRepository:
  @classmethod
  def create(cls, student):
    with open("students.csv", "a") as file:
      file.write(student.to_csv_line())

  @classmethod
  def edit(cls, student):
    with fileinput.FileInput("students.csv", inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
      for line in file:
        data = line.split(",")
        if (data[0] == student.id):
          line = student.to_csv_line()
        print(line, end='')

  @classmethod
  def search(cls, id):
    student = None
    with open("students.csv", "r") as file:
      for line in file:
        data = line.strip().split(",")
        if data[0] == id:
          student = Student()
          student.id = data[0]
          student.name = data[1]
          student.age = int(data[2])
          student.address = data[3]
          return student


# Menú principal
def menu():
  option = input("""
  +==========================================+
  |                                          |
  |          Control de estudiantes          |
  |                                          |
  +==========================================+

  [?] Seleccione opción:

  1. Ingresar un estudiante
  2. Buscar un estudiante
  3. Salir

  > """)

  if option == "1":
    student = Student()
    student.fill()
    StudentRepository.create(student)
    print("""
  [✓] Estudiante creado.
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
    """)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    system("cls")
    return menu()

  if option == "2":
    id = input("\nIngresa el ID: ")
    student = StudentRepository.search(id)
    if student is not None:
      return search_menu(student)
    else:
      print("""
  [✕] Estudiante no encontrado.
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
      """)
      time.sleep(1.5)
      system("cls") # limpia la pantalla
      menu()
  if option == "3":
    print("Good Bye")
    sys.exit(0)

# Menú de búsqueda
def search_menu(student):
  option = input(f"""
  [✓] Estudiante encontrado:

  ID: {student.id}
  Nombre: {student.name}
  Edad: {student.age}
  Dirección: {student.address}

  [?] Seleccione opción:

  1. Editar estudiante
  3. Volver

  > """)

  if (option == "1"):
    student.edit_mode()
    StudentRepository.edit(student)
    print("""
  [✓] Estudiante actualizado:
  [↺] Volviendo al menú en 2s
    """)
    time.sleep(2)
    system("cls")
    return menu()
  if option == "3":
    system("cls")
    return menu()

menu()
```

El menú está adaptado a Windows  a la hora de limpiar la consola (`system("cls")`), si usas Linux dejalo como lo tienes (`system("clear")`).

Los PEP recomiendan usar `cls` en vez de `self` en los métodos de clase, a diferencia de los métodos de instancia, de todas formas es una recomendación no un error.

Comment: si te agrasdeco la ayuda, y disculpa si soy muy necio en relidad hay varias cosas del codigo de gustavo que no entiendo y si es para un proyecto en realidad soy nuevo en esto y me cuesta un poco lo que necesito es crear un programa que que me permita ingresar varios estudiantes por su id,nombre,direccion y edad ,almacenalo luego en un archivo, cuando lo requiera buscar a al estudiante por su id y luego editar los datos de ese estudiante y que modifiquen en el archivo tambien

Comment: me podrias ayudar con un metodo mas simple para hacerlo y que si entienda bien

Comment: Una forma más sencilla es usar un diccionario en el que las claves sean las ids y los valores otro diccionario con las claves  nombre, edad, direccion y sus respectivos valores. `datos={'1':{'nombre':'fulano', 'edad': 12, 'direccion': 'Calle....'}, '2':{'nombre':'mengano', 'edad': 17, 'direccion': 'Calle....'},}`. Los datos los guardas como hace Gustavo (separados por comas), los lees de la misma forma (`split` y `strip`) y cargas todos los datos en memoria usando el diccionario. Trabajas sobre el (añadir, buscar y editar) y luego sobreescribes el archivo con los datos del diccionario.

Comment: Una forma aún más simple aunque más ineficiente es usar una lista de listas `datos=[['1, ', 'fulano', '12', 'Calle...'],['2, ', 'mengano', '17', 'Calle...']]` las busquedas las haces por indice en este caso. Puedes cargar los datos con `datos = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f.readlines()]`, simplemente. Para guardar solo necesitas usar algo como `f.writeline(','.join(dato)[:-1])` donde dato es un elemento de datos.